# K8s - Schedule new pod until the old one is fully terminated

Tags: kubernetes

I am using `RollingUpdate`, the behavior is, one replica will be mark as terminating, and then a new pod will be brought up as pending state. However, what I want is that a new pod is brought up only when one old replica is fully terminated instead of just start terminating.

```
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 0
```

Comment: I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If yes, please upvote and accept the answer. If not, I am happy to assist further.

Answer (score 0):

An "[Disruption Budget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/#how-disruption-budgets-work)" can be used to configure the scale-down behavior.

You can specify the maxUnavailable and minAvailable number of pods during intentional disruptions, such as node draining, in your deployment manifest. To learn how to accomplish that, refer to the [K8s Documentation.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/#protecting-an-application-with-a-poddisruptionbudget)

Looks like it's the **maxUnavailable: 1**; By setting it to **maxUnavailable :0**  you were able to easily replicate your experience setting that value and easily get the right experience.

Since there is exactly one replica in the ready state, that is the intended state for K8s. It will generate a new Pod during a [Rolling Update operation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-update-deployment), the approach you asked, making the total number of Pods two. However, you gave K8s authorization to keep one Pod inaccessible.

Then you instructed it to maintain the necessary quantity of Pods at one. It therefore satisfied each of those requirements: 1 Pod, the intended count, allowed by the Rolling update  strategy in an unavailable state.

You can correctly instruct K8s to never allow any Pod to be unavailable by setting the maxUnavailable to zero, even if doing so requires surging Pods above the replica count for a short period of time.

```
Spec:
 replicas: 1 
 strategy: 
   rollingUpdate:
           maxSurge: 1
                 maxUnavailable: 0
               type: RollingUpdate
```

This will launch a second pod; watch for it to become healthy and make sure your startup, readiness, and liveliness probes are working.

Refer to this [blog](https://www.bluematador.com/blog/kubernetes-deployments-rolling-update-configuration) by bluematador and [blog](https://medium.com/brexeng/kubernetes-rolling-update-and-termination-grace-periods-d922c6b84d88) by medium to know Kubernetes Rolling Update Configuration.